# Quite or pretty?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

I took this sentence from the students book. What is the best choice:

> Being a doctor is a **quite/ pretty** stressful job?

In the book “pretty” is given as a correct variant, but with no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X is **quite a stressful job**. [standard register]

X is **a pretty stressful job**. [informal register]

The book should give both and explain both.

Comment: I just want to emphasize a detail in Lambie's answer. The hint is in the article placement. "Quite" comes BEFORE the article: Quite A stressful job. "Pretty" comes after the article: A pretty stressful job. 

Why does "quite" precede the article? That's a different question entirely. But, at least we can use that difference to help distinguish between words like "quite" and "pretty".

Comment: @fjack That's absolutely right.

Comment: @fjack **a quite stressful job** is also grammatical. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+quite+stressful%22&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJjratycfdAhVmhuAKHTe1AfIQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1664&bih=1062

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo perhaps "a quite stressful" is grammatical, but it's also so unusual that Google's Ngram viewer can't find it! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+quite+stressful%2Cquite+a+stressful&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquite%20a%20stressful%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @fjack: First, it isn't unusual. I'm a native speaker of AmE and know that for a fact.  It is frequently used in American English. Did you consult the link I provided? That NGram doesn't know about it, while Google Books does, is something you should take up with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are very useful for English learners.

> 3. adverb [ADVERB adjective/adverb]
>      You can use pretty before an adjective or adverb to mean 'quite' or 'rather'.
>      [informal]
>
> I had a pretty good idea what she was going to do.
>   Pretty soon after my arrival I found lodgings.
>
> Synonyms: fairly, rather, quite, kind of [informal]

[Pretty (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pretty)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know, what “pretty” means, but I don’t understand: why “quite” is not suitable in my sentence.

Comment: 'Quite' is definitely suitable in your sentence in British English, but I suspect that although it is correct in American English, it is not much used. Who told you it was wrong?